# Can you put 2012 macbook air 13 inch ssd in macbook air 11 inch 2012?

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

I am thinking about doing something like that. Or would it not work?

Comment: It was perfectly clear to me what Jake was asking and why I took the time to look up the specs on both models to verify the SSD were interchangeable between them and  answered the question in the Title.  IMO the "**put on hold**" is at times taken to the extreme, as in this case!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will work as they are the same type SSD between those two models.